# Do multiple asynchronous validations without nesting

Tags: angular, promise

I frequently encounter use cases where I have to do several asynchronous validations before I can do a task. say, `doValidationX()` returns a promise which succeeds if validation is successful and fails otherwise. Following is how I handle such cases currently.

```
this.doValidation1(object).then(() => {
   this.doValidation2(object).then(() => {
       this.doValidation3(object).then(() => {
           this.doValidation4(object).then(() => {
               this.doValidation5(object).then(() => {
                    //Do something.
               }).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
           }).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
       }).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
   }).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
}).catch(reason => console.log(reason));
```

Due to the nesting, it is very unreadable. Is there a way to avoid nesting and organize this code in a more readable way? I tried to use `Promise.all()`, but soon realized that all validations run at once if I do so. I only want to run second validation if the first validation succeeds.

Comment: Can you try async await?

Comment: This has been asked and answered many times here.  The operative word is "promise chaining".

Comment: Have you considered doing observables instead? They do a great job of handling async operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was quite simpler than I thought. Thanks @jfriend00 for pointing me the right direction.

```
this.doValidation1(object)
    .then(() => this.doValidation2(object))
    .then(() => this.doValidation3(object))
    .then(() => this.doValidation4(object))
    .then(() => this.doValidation5(object))
    .then(() => {
        //Do something
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, that approach may not be the best. Your validations seem to be **independent**, yet you're waiting for every validation to finish before the next validation fires. This lead to an unnecessary idle time: should your validations take 1 second -for instance- your code will spent 5 seconds to run. This is unneeded if you can run the promises in parallel (thus waiting only one second).

[One way to do so is to use Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), which runs an array of promises in parallel and resolves to true when all of them resolve successfully, rejects otherwise:

```
Promise.all([
  this.doValidation1(object),
  this.doValidation2(object),
  this.doValidation3(object),
  this.doValidation4(object),
  this.doValidation5(object),
]).then(() => {
  //validation passed
}).catch((e) => {
  // validation failed.
});
```

However, when promises are **not independent**  (you need the result of your first promise in the second, and so), your approach is correct.